# How to get the count of total number of files and store it in a table? Also how to load a structure of a table into multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can you get the count of files in a folder using SQL query…? Also how to load a structure stored in another database to multiple tables in another database and also how to load the data from the files in these tables? And the tables should be created dynamically with different names

Comment: You've got three questions stuffed into one. Try breaking them up, as they have completely different answers. Also try searching, because all of those questions already have answers (both on SO and elsewhere). Last but not least, make it clear what "files in these tables" means -- tables that are storing file paths, or tables holding `FILESTREAM` data?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried googling this?

Comment: Yes Sir I did search on Google

Answer (score 0):

well....sql has lots of tools hidden....try [xp_dirtree](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/26/sql-server-get-directory-structure-using-extended-stored-procedure-xp_dirtree/). All the undocumented directory and file related stored procs in sql server as of 2014 [here](https://sqlnotesfromtheunderground.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/by-example-undocumented-sql-stored-procedures-drive-folder-and-file-manipulation/).

I do not see an easy way to build your "load structure of a table into multiple tables" but you may eventually get there with loops and xp_subdirs or enabling xp_cmdshell and doing it in dos through sql.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#directory','U') is not null
    begin
        drop table #directory;
    end;
create table #directory (
     [subdirectory] varchar(512) --not a full path, just directory or file name
    ,[depth] int
    ,[file] int
);
insert into #directory ([subdirectory],[depth],[file])
exec xp_dirtree 'C:\Program Files\',0,1; -- all levels down, so all files and folders in entire tree
--exec xp_dirtree 'C:\Program Files\',1,1; -- only one level 
--exec xp_dirtree 'C:\Program Files\',2,1; -- two levels

select [subdirectory],[depth] from #directory
where [file] = 1 -- 0 is a directory

select count(1) 
from #directory
where [file] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have used xp_cmdshell instead of dirtree and got the list of files. But now the real scenario is to load the structure into the tables and then I need to load the data from the files into those tables... This is my real concern

Comment: to load is as shown above, create a table with the same structure as the output, only one column with xp_cmdshell then insert into (myonecolumn) exec xp_cmdshell 'my dos command', you can add an identity column too since it's not insertable.